Isometric approximation
In the article Isometric Approximation  by P. Alestalo, D. A. Trotsenko and J.VäiSäLä, the authors show the following results:
If $A$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $f:A\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is an $\epsilon d(A)$ isometry, then there exists an isometry  $S$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that for all $x\in A$
$$|f(x)- S(x)|\leq c_n \sqrt{\epsilon}d(A)$$
where $0<\epsilon<1$, $d(A)$ is the Euclidean diameter of $A$
The constant $c_n$  depends only of $n$.
An $\epsilon$-isometry  is $\forall x, x'\in K$
$$||f(x)-f(x')|-|x-x'||\leq \epsilon.$$
My question is whether anyone knows of similar results for the Poincaré disk or can provide a reference in the context of hyperbolic spaces.
